# The correct mySQL syntax for using the ON keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

The question stated was this:

What are the titles, author’s names, and prices for pre-owned books that are priced at $50.00 or below? Results should be sorted by price in descending order, followed by title in A-Z order.

CODE:

```
SELECT book.title, author.LastName, author.firstName, Ownersbook.price 
FROM book, author, ownersbook 
ON book.isbn = bookauthor.isbn 
WHERE Ownersbook.price < 50 
ORDER BY Ownersbook.price DESC, book.title ASC;
```

I want the table to look like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| title                                           | lastname   | firstname | price |
+-------------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| ER, SOM, NF, DK/NF, SQL, JDBC, ODBC, and RELVAR | Stratton   | Bill      | 50.00 |
| My Love's Last Longing                          | Heartthrob | Danielle  | 50.00 |
| How to Keep your Cable Bill Down                | Hartpence  | Bruce     | 45.00 |
| Yes! Networking is for Bills Fans               | Lutz       | Peter     | 40.00 |
| Yes! Networking is for Bills Fans               | Phelps     | Andrew    | 40.00 |
| Yes! Networking is for Bills Fans               | Leone      | James     | 40.00 |
| The Shortest Book in the World                  | Phelps     | Andrew    | 35.00 |
| How to Keep your Cellular Bill Down             | Hartpence  | Bruce     | 25.00 |
| My Lost Love's Long Last Lingering              | Heartthrob | Danielle  | 25.00 |
| From the Shores of Lake Erie to IT              | Stratton   | Bill      |  0.00 |
+-------------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried getting rid of the ON keyword statement, but it just duplicates a lot of data forever and I don't want that. I'm not sure how the ON keyword is used correctly.

ERROR:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON bo
ok.isbn = bookauthor.isbn
WHERE Ownersbook.price < 50
ORDER BY book.title' at line 2
```

Comment: When you list the tables in the FROM clause like this `FROM book, author, ownersbook`, they are `CROSS JOIN`ed, thats why you are getting duplicates. You have to write the JOIN condition in the WHERE clause instead of the ON clause. Otherwise, use the JOIN syntax using the INNER JOIN or any other join type with ON clause to write the conditions

Answer (score 2):

Your query needs rework for using the ON clause properly. Assuming isbn column exists in all the three tables, here's the query:

```
SELECT book.title, author.LastName, author.firstName, Ownersbook.price 
FROM 
    book
inner 
    join author 
ON  book.isbn = author.isbn 
inner 
    join Ownersbook
ON book.isbn = Ownersbook.isbn
WHERE Ownersbook.price < 50 
ORDER BY Ownersbook.price DESC, book.title ASC;
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ON` keyword with out join, you should put your condition in `where` clause

```
SELECT book.title, author.LastName, author.firstName, Ownersbook.price 
FROM book, author, ownersbook 
WHERE Ownersbook.price < 50 
and book.isbn = bookauthor.isbn 
-- here you have to add condition with ownersbook and some table
-- here you have to add condition with bookauthor and some table
ORDER BY Ownersbook.price DESC, book.title ASC;
```

good practice is to use aliases, please consdier below example

```
SELECT b.title, a.LastName, a.firstName, ob.price 
FROM book b, author a  ownersbook ob, bookauthor ba
WHERE ob.price < 50 
and b.isbn = ba.isbn 
-- here you have to add condition with ownersbook and some table
-- here you have to add condition with bookauthor and some table
ORDER BY ob.price DESC, b.title ASC;
```

Comment: Any explanation or should just take your (lack of)word for it?

Answer (score 1):

ON statement, in mySQL, is a complement for [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/join.html).

I would try this

```
SELECT book.title, author.LastName, author.firstName, Ownersbook.price 
FROM book, author, ownersbook 
WHERE Ownersbook.price < 50 
AND book.isbn = bookauthor.isbn 
ORDER BY Ownersbook.price DESC, book.title ASC;
```